# What would happen if someone used an Engorgement charm on a human?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory

The engorgement charm in used on spiders multiple times in the series, proving it can be used on living things.

At one point, Ron states that he beileived Hagrid had been hit with an Engorgement charm as a child.

So, what would happen? Could the affected person actually be grown to a Hagrid-like size? If so, would they stay that way until it was reversed, or would it wear off?

Comment: Students learn *Engorgio* and *Reducio* at the same time, to avoid any adverse effects from something too large. (Can't remember if it's mentioned in the books, but it shows up in a video game written by JKR.) This suggests that perhaps it doesn't wear off on its own, although it could also be to prevent you from being attacked by a giant spider or something.

Comment: http://youtu.be/QCPN3KmWEMA?t=6m39s

Comment: i believe hermionie even uses reducio on her teeth, and it only mentions she did it once. though they never specifically say that is the charm she used she did reduce the size of her front teeth in book 4.

Comment: @Himarm Did the books actually say that? I don't remember anything about her shrinking her teeth.

Comment: im pretty sure it mentions it though i dont have the quote with me, harrys talking to her and suddenly goes,... hermione your teeth. and she says something about wanting to do it for ages but her parents where against it since they were dentists. she has buck teeth when first described in book 1 i believe, but that is what she corrects.

Comment: @Himarm -- Malfoy tries to curse Harry with a *Densaugeo* spell and mistakenly hits Hermione in *Goblet of Fire*. *Reducio* is never mentioned by name. Hermione says, "*‘Well ... when I went up to Madam Pomfrey to get them
shrunk, she held up a mirror, and told me to stop her when
they were back to how they normally were,’ she said. ‘And I just ... let her carry on a bit.*’ So it was Madam Pomfrey who shrunk Hermione's teeth back to their normal, then smaller, size. Hermione was pretty pleased about this! :)

Comment: In light of the canon (and explicit) use of Engorgio on a human in my answer, I thought that you might wish to reconsider your acceptance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask Aunt Marge!

[image]

While Harry's magic was involuntary,  and it's not explicitly stated in canon, I would be willing to wager that some sort of engorgement magic was involved in blowing her up in *Prisoner of Azkaban*. She survived the engorgement, was properly punctured by the Accidental Magic Reversal Squad, her memory modified, and deemed fit to continue living her life as before by Cornelius Fudge.

Canon never implicitly states all the things that might happen when an engorgement charm is used on a human. We can deduce from Ron's comment about Hagrid is that it may be possible, at the very least, to do an engorgement charm on a **half-human/half-giant**. If this is possible, one would have to ask if it's Hagrid's giant blood that protects him from being injured or killed by the engorgement charm, or keeps the engorgement charm finite (i.e. Hagrid doesn't keep enlarging until he blows up!). Again, this is just an *idea* based on canon, as most examples of *Engorgio* are done on non-human subjects:

- The twins placed an Engorgement Charm on the Ton-Tongue Toffee that
  they "accidentally" dropped in front of Dudley (GF4).
- Kevin, the little wizard boy in the World Cup campground, was casting
  an Engorgement Spell (or something very similar) on a slug (GF7).
- Hermione suspected that Hagrid has used an Engorgement Charm on his
  pumpkins (CS7).
- The fake Moody used an Engorgement Charm on each of the three spiders
  he had bought to class to demonstrate the Unforgivable Curses (GF14).
- Harry cast this on a spider to practice with his wand (DH20).

Thanks to the [Harry Potter Lexicon (E Spells)](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/spells/spells_e.html) for the above list.

Dudley Dursley's tongue didn't keep growing, although it got very long, after the twins fed him the tongue-ton toffee, so he didn't explode eventually, or die.

**I conclude that engorgement charms *can* be used on humans, but with little harm done. Aunt Marge (I believe) and Dudley are all examples of humans surviving engorgement magic.**

Comment: Wasn't Ron making that comment when he first learned that Hagrid was half-giant? Meaning that his now-defunct theory that an Engorgement charm was responsible for Hagrid's size did not take into account the effects of giant heritage.

Comment: @numaroth -- Possibly? The OP didn't cite the quote, so I'm not sure which book it came from, so I don't know. But I did take Hagrid's half-giant heritage into consideration and noted it in my answer. Do you have further questions about it that you feel I should have specifically  addressed? :)

Comment: The "spell" used on aunt Marge didn't seem to be a normal engorgement charm. Nothing else that has the charm used on it reacts that way.

Comment: @Slytherincess What I meant is that Ron wasn't taking Hagrid's half-giant heritage into account.  IIRC, Ron had just been told that Hagrid was a half-giant. He was surprised and said that he had assumed that Hagrid's size came from an Engorgement charm. Implying that he had not thought about Hagrid being a giant before this point. Thus his comment should be used as an expectation for the effects of an Engorgement charm on a human not a half-giant.

Comment: @numaroth Is right. Chapter 23 of GoF: “I know there isn’t, but … blimey, no wonder he keeps it quiet,” Ron said, shaking his head. “I always thought he’d got in the way of a bad Engorgement Charm when he was a kid or something. Didn’t like to mention it. …”

Comment: @numaroth - Thanks for explaining it differently. I get where you're coming from now. That's what I was *trying* to say about Ron's comment about Hagrid (again, not knowing the exact quote), but you say it much more succinctly. You should leave an answer! :)

Comment: @WinterKnight -- Thanks for providing the source for Ron's comment about Hagrid. It helped to put the OP's comment into perspective. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @WinterKnight - Regarding Aunt Marge, I tried to be careful to say "engorgement magic" rather than call it an engorgement spell proper. Harry didn't cast a spell when Aunt Marge, uh, *expanded* ... it happened spontaneously, due to his anger. It was accidental. I'm merely proposing it was some kind of engorgement magic that caused Marge to blow up like a balloon. I may be way off, though. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Nah, I wouldn't feel right leaving an answer that was just a reworked section of your answer and I don't have anything new to add.

Comment: @Slytherincess No problem. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

In [Harry Potter and the Cursed Child](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29056083-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child), Albus Potter and Scorpius Malfoy travel in time and use the Engorgio spell on Cedric Diggory during the second event of the Tri-Wizard Cup.

For the record, they initially thought about engorgio'ing ***only his head***, but evidently settled on blowing his whole self up. Basically he turns into a balloon, in much the same way that [Aunt Marge](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Marjorie_Dursley) did in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban

> CEDRIC DIGGORY approaches them through the water, a bubble over his
>   head. ALBUS and SCORPIUS raise their wands together and fire an
>   Engorgement Charm through the water.
>
> He turns and looks at them, confused. And it hits him. And around him
>   the water glows gold.
>
> And then CEDRIC starts to grow — and grow again — and grow some more.
>   He looks around himself — entirely panicked. And the boys watch as
>   CEDRIC ascends helplessly through the water.
>
> **LUDO BAGMAN:** *But no, what’s this . . . Cedric Diggory is ascending out of the water
>   and seemingly out of the competition. Oh, ladies and gentlemen, we
>   don’t have our winner but we certainly have our loser. **Cedric Diggory
>   is turning into a balloon, and this balloon wants to fly. Fly, ladies
>   and gentlemen, fly.** Fly out of the task and out of the tournament and
>   — oh my, it gets wilder still, around Cedric, fireworks explode
>   declaiming — “Ron loves Hermione” — and the crowd love that — oh,
>   ladies and gentlemen, the look on Cedric’s face. It’s quite some
>   picture, it’s quite some sight, it’s quite some tragedy. This is a
>   humiliation, there’s no other word for it.*